# CSS and image file not working in heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am working on a small web app and it works fine on my laptop. But when deployed on heroku, the styling and image is missing.

Web App Link: https://vast-crag-53030.herokuapp.com/

Code Repository: https://github.com/alokshrotri/commuteStats

I am using rails 5 and am on Windows 7

I was able to run the below command, commited to github and redeployed on heroku but to no avail.

> bundle exec rake assets:precompile

If I run with RAILS_ENV=production, I get an error as shown below. Here (= require_tree .) is uncommented.

```
C:\Users\u0126252\Documents\GitHub\commuteStats\bin [master ≡ +0 ~3 -0 !]> bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
(in C:/Users/u0126252/Documents/GitHub/commuteStats)
rake aborted!
ExecJS::RuntimeError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: eof (undefined)

Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

If I comment (//= require_tree .) then the output is different.

```
C:\Users\u0126252\Documents\GitHub\commuteStats\bin [master ≡ +0 ~1 -0 !]> bundl
e exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
(in C:/Users/u0126252/Documents/GitHub/commuteStats)
rake aborted!
ExecJS::ProgramError: TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method

Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
C:\Users\u0126252\Documents\GitHub\commuteStats\bin [master ≡ +0 ~1 -0 !]>
```

Have tried reading several posts around this but it hasn't helped. I certainly do not want to add config.assets.compile = true to the code.

Any help around it would be great. Environment details below. Happy to provide any other information required.

```
C:\Users\u0126252\Documents\GitHub\commuteStats\bin [master ≡ +0 ~1 -0 !]> rails
 -v
Rails 5.0.2
C:\Users\u0126252\Documents\GitHub\commuteStats\bin [master ≡ +0 ~1 -0 !]> ruby
--version
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x64-mingw32]

C:\Users\u0126252\Documents\GitHub\commuteStats\bin [master ≡ +0 ~1 -0 !]> syste
minfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name" /C:"OS Version"
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise
OS Version:                6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
C:\Users\u0126252\Documents\GitHub\commuteStats\bin [master ≡ +0 ~1 -0 !]>
```

Comment: What happens if you remove "assets" from the uri? `<%= image_tag 'button.png' %>` Also, why are you using the html link tag for your application.css in your application.html.erb layout? Try replacing that with `<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>`

Comment: @Dithanial If I just use <%= image_tag 'button.png' %>, then I am getting an error "TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method". I am new to html and css coding. Will read more on stylesheet_link_tag line and edit. Will let you know the result.

Comment: What error are you getting? And did changing your stylesheet link work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I'd start with the easy one first, the image isn't displaying because you're telling it to look in the wrong place. Change to:

```
<%= image_tag "button.png" %>
```

Second, you can get the stylesheet to display in one of two ways:

change `config.assets.compile = false` to true (not recommended)

or add

`<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>`

as Dithanial write in the comment and leave the flag set to false.

Here's a working live version:  https://polar-refuge-16359.herokuapp.com/

I'll make a PR on your GitHub repo and you can see what I did to the version that's on Heroku.

Comment: This works great. I have merged the code and my issue is resolved. Have upvoted the answer but it is not visible due to my low reputation points. Thanks so much for helping.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it helped you :) You can also accept the answer if your issue is resolved.